# Why does cmd prompt say java version is "17.0.5" while about java shows version 8?

Tags: java, windows

Using java -version command in cmd prompt, it shows that java version is "17.0.5". However, when I select "about java" from the start window icon, it says version 8 (build 1.8.0).

I just updated to jdk 17.0.5. Are the jdk version and java version different things?

Comment: did you update your PATH variable?

Comment: I updated JAVA_HOME under System Variables, and added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the System Variables path.

Comment: As long as `java -version` returns 17.0.5, you do not need to worry. All the applications will refer to this version only. Most likely 'About Java' refers to the JRE installed by Windows. If you want to get rid of it, you can remove it from the Control Panel.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that does make sense. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

command prompt get the version from the JAVA_HOME you need to set it to the version you want.
It's better you delete all versions and install the one you want to use.